# Call function periodically in Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cron

we need run one function periodically in Java web application .
How to call function of some class periodically ?
Is there any way that call function when some event occured like high load in server and so on . what is crontab ? Is that work periodically ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To call something periodically, see [TimerTask](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html)

Answer (score 5):

If you need something more robust you can use [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/)

As for `crontab` is the scheduling tool on Unix machines.

Comment: More robust than TimerTask? It's just more flexible.

Comment: @BalusC: Robust would be, with Quartz, you can schedule different kinds of objects, you can use JTA transactions, clustering and many other Java EE features.

Comment: @Brian. Well yes, it depends of your concept of robustness then. One of the extra features Quartz has is persistence between system restarts. That is a future alone, yes, but it is a future that add robustness to the library anyway, at least in my point of view.

Comment: @Oscar - yes. That particular feature does sound like a robustness feature

Comment: Robustness refers to how reliably it does the tasks it claims to do. TimerTask is for scheduling stuff within a Java session. Quartz is just fuller featured.

Answer (score 4):

For calling methods when server has high load, you have at least two possible approaches. Your App Server might have management hooks that would you allow to monitor its behaviour and take progrommatic action. Alterntaively you have some system monitoring capability (Eg. Tivoli or OpenView) and it generates "events", it should not be too hard to deliver such events as (for example) JMS messages and have your server pick them up.

However, you might want to explain a bit more about what you want to achieve. Adaptive application beahviour might be quite tricky to get right.

Answer (score 2):

> we need run one function periodically
>   in Java web application

(1) So look in your deployment descriptor (web.xml) define a listener to startup at startup time.

> How to call function of some class
>   periodically ?

(2) Create a [Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) in the listener.

> Is there any way that call function
>   when some event occured like high load
>   in server and so on

(3) and run some Threads to check for system conditions that are accesible with Java, even run system progs (uptime, etc) and parse the output.

crontab could be a way but the execution of Java will start another JVM and that is really the hot thing in servlet containers: all runs in the same JVM.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget about java.util.concurrent - it has a lot of classes for scheduling, e.g. ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, if you need more than a simple Timer.

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html

There is also a backport of it to Java 1.4: [http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net](http://backport-jsr166.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

If you already use Spring, you might want to have a look at Spring's task execution framework - using @Scheduled and @Async for annotating methods as tasks and implementing the functionality in a Processor that delegates the actual work to a Worker, as described in:

http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/05/task-scheduling-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/

The advantage is that you can define timers using a cron-like syntax in your spring context and you don't need anything special to set up tasks, it is also well integrated into Java EE applications and should play well with web servers (which custom Threads tend not to do always).

Answer (score 1):

> How to call function of some class periodically?

There are several solutions: a [Timer](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html), a Java cron implementation like [cron4j](http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/cron4j/), [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/), or even the [EJB Timer API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html). Choosing one or the other highly depends on the context: the type of application, the technologies used, the number of jobs, etc.

> Is there any way that call function when some event occurred like high load in server and so on

You could maybe use JMX in your jobs to access and monitor informations and trigger an action under some specific condition. But this is more a pull mode, not event based.