# Generating files on java web server

Tags: java, web-applications

I have a web service which generates a bunch of files on the server (say tomcat), which get zipped up and streamed back to the client through the servlet's OutputStream.

This part is clear. The part that I am struggling with is how to manage these files so that if two client happen to use this feature at the same time.

I can think of several possible solutions and I am not sure what is the simplest and best way to handle this and would love to hear some thoughts.

For example: I could create a directory with the time-stamp appended to the directory name e.g. `tmp_123142345` and delete this folder after I'm done writing the zip file to the stream.  It's very unlikely that two people will try to download the same file in the same millisecond.

But, is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely, but not impossible. You will probably want a solution that you can boast in board meeting that it's collision free. :)

Have a global synchronized counter or better `AtomicLong` counter. Create the directory name like `"tmp_"+ (atomicLongCounter.addAndGet(1))`

So each will have unique directory even if they landed at the same millisecond.

Comment: Ok, that is little bit better but almost the same.  I was looking to see if there may be a better approach altogether...

Comment: AtomicLong is super cool, thanks!  I'll use `incrementAndGet `http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html#incrementAndGet()

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is ok, but you really don't need to delete the files. You can just write a task in your task manager that is responsible to delete all these files once a day (just cleaning the directory). Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755880/call-function-periodically-in-java), there are some solutions to make de directory clean.

Comment: Well, I am worried about over flooding the directory.  Yes, I could clean the files once a day, but who knows if someone may be downloading something at that time?

Comment: I understand your point, but your application is used worldwide os just in your location? If it is used just in your location, you can fix a time to run the task, perhaps during the dawn, reducing the possibillity of some user is being downloading some file.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use [`java.util.UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html)? It will get you get unique ids that you can append to the file names.

Comment: Yes, it would also work... I am really hoping to find a cleaner way... Maybe it does not exist :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method createTempFile which is in the File class. This will let Java create a unique folder for you where you can put your files...